# Python and PYQT directory is

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to run a command line in a GUI using os.system to help our less techie office workers. I am using os.system..as I had tons of trouble with subprocess. I am close but I am getting a weird output of my directory path..

```
def selectFile(self):


    self.listWidget.clear() # In case there are any existing elements in the list
    directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Pick a folder")
    print directory


    for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
        if file_name.endswith(".csv"):
            self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)
            print (file_name)
    self.directory = directory





def osconvertfile(self):


    directoryPath = self.directory
    print directoryPath

    cmd = ('python /Users/eeamesX/work/data-scripts/longFileScripts/createXMLFromCSVSept.py '
           +str(directoryPath))
    print cmd
    os.system(cmd)
```

I am getting an error or wrong directory due to ./ being added on..

```
.//Users/eeamesX/work/data/Sept_1_upload/priority_2/transcriptsAudoSplits/09012015_331_male3_r1_seg1/
```

Any way to fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) and [os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath)?

```
def osconvertfile(self):
    directoryPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.normpath(self.directory))
    print directoryPath

    cmd = 'python /Users/eeamesX/work/data-scripts/longFileScripts/createXMLFromCSVSept.py %s' directoryPath
    print cmd
    os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: If you are using PyQt4 you need to use `path.startsWith( ... )` : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstring.html. If you are using PyQt5 instead, `QString` is automatically converted to python `str`